# D3 Scatterplot with thousands of data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to make a scatter plot using D3 with the ability of only looking at a small section at a time using some sort of slider across the x-axis.  Is there a method in javascript where I can efficiently buffer the data and quickly access the elements as the user scrolls left or right?

My goal is similar to this protovis example [here](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/zoom.html), but with 10 times the amount of data. This example chokes when I make that many data points.

Answer (score 8):

I have done a scatterplot with around 10k points where I needed to filter sections of the plot interactively.
I share a series of tips that worked for me, which I hope some may hopefully help you too:

- Use a key function for your `.data()` operator as it is done at the end of this [tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html). The advantage of using keys is that you do not need to update elements that do not change.
- Not related to d3, but I divided my data space into a grid, so that each data point is associated to a single cell (in other words each cell is an index to a set of points). In this way, when I needed to access from, let's say, from x_0 to x_1, I knew what cells I needed, and hence I could access a much more refined set of possible data points (avoiding iterating along all points).
- Avoid transitions: from my personal experiences the `.transition()` is not very smooth when thousand of SVG elements are selected (it may be better now in newer versions or with faster processors)
- In my case it was more convenient to make points invisible (`.attr("display","none")`) or visible rather than removing and creating SVG elements (I wonder if this is more time efficient too)